# Network Monitoring Tool Recommendation

Tags: network-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Network Traffic Monitoring](https://serverfault.com/questions/3326/network-traffic-monitoring)

Hello,

My company is looking for a monitoring app/tool that would allow us to capture and graph statistics on network performance. As a starting point, we would like to ping remote host(s) and gateway(s) from several of our servers, grab an average of the ping times from each of our servers to the remote host(s), and then graph it (preferably in a central location). Also, we would like to be able to graph the results for time frames as short as a week to as long as 6 months.

It is reasonable to expect that we would ask more of the selected monitoring app/tool as we come up with other key network performance indicators in the future. So an app with great flexibility and features would be ideal.

Upon first glance, Cacti looks like it might be a fit. Any other recommendations?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Hasn't this been done, about a million times?
http://serverfault.com/questions/3326/network-traffic-monitoring
http://serverfault.com/questions/68390/graphical-app-for-network-usage-monitoring
http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers

Answer (score 3):

[zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) for alerting and trend-plotting, [nagios](http://nagios.org) for alerting + [nagios grapher](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nagiosgrapher/) for trend plotting, [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) - for trend plotting.

nagios + munin [as two separate setups] are tool of choice for me.

from things i've never tried: [opsview](http://www.opsview.org/) and [centreon](http://www.centreon.com/).

Comment: +1 for zabbix, haven't seen that before, looks decent.


I use Nagios/Cacti.

Comment: Thanks to all for the input and the links to other threads.